# How to find n-letter word in text file?

Tags: python, string, text

I am trying to find one-letter word, two-letter word, three-letter word and so on, for a shakespeare sonnet text file. I want to find n-letter words, assign them in a separate list according to 'n' letters in the form of list.

How  shall i proceed with such a file?

Comment: wheres's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

1. Get the text
2. Split all words
3. Put them in a data type (such as `pd.DataFrame`)
4. Calculate the length for each word
5. Query the data type
6. DIY: remove non-word characters

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Get data & split
shakespear_words = requests \
    .get('https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt') \
    .text \
    .split()

# Create pd.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': shakespear_words})

# Calculate word lengths
df['word_length'] = df.words.str.len()

# Query your data
df[df.word_length == 4]
```

Comment: if i want to find unique words from this frame?

Comment: `df[df.word_length == 4].words.unique()`. Now I am done doing your homework, good luck! If you want to learn more about python please use the following link: www.google.com